# How can i rotate screen when use video player full screen in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on application in unity3d and my orientation is portrait.
So when i play video on fullscreen mode with :

```
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(vClip, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full);
```

my video play on fullscreen but in portrait.But i want play it in landscape mode.
I try:

```
public void PlayVideo()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlayFullVideoCoroutine());
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
    print("Play Full Video Coroutine!");
}
IEnumerator PlayFullVideoCoroutine()
{
     Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(vClip, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full);
     yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
     Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
     print("Full Video Playback Completed.");
}
```

It's working but when video finish , the application orientation don't change to portrait.
Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

So I experimented with [Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html) and as is stated in the documentation:

> Calling this function will pause Unity during movie playback. When playback finishes Unity will resume.

This is an indication of a **timing issue**. So I setup the following code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Testy : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayVideo());
    }


    public IEnumerator PlayVideo()
    {
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("video.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    }
}
```

In my experiment I found that if I added a one second wait after setting the orientation using `Screen.orientation` it would work, but if I only waited a single frame it wouldn't.

## The solution

Add a `yield return new WaitforSeconds(1f)` after changing the orientation to ensure the orientation is changed. I know this isn't the most pretty code but it seems to do the job.